# success function wont fire in jquery ajax

Tags: django, jquery

I have this ajax code to remove a record form database:

```
function f(id) {
                $.ajax({
                    url: "/meeting/delParticipant/"+id+"/",
                    type: "POST",
                    success: function(res){
                        alert ('success');
                        $('#participants tr:last').prev().remove();
                    }
                });
            };
```

and I have a table in template that each row has an anchor to call this:

```
field1  field2  field3 <a href="#" onClick="f(1)" >del</a>
field1  field2  field3 <a href="#" onClick="f(2)" >del</a>
field1  field2  field3 <a href="#" onClick="f(3)" >del</a>
...
```

It remove the record successfully but `success function` wont fire and I don't know why!

Comment: Maybe you forget to disable csrf-token in views file (decorator @csrf_exempt for your view function)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Try this code it would fire ajax success**

```
 $.ajax({
                    data:id,
                    url: "/meeting/delParticipant/",
                    type: "POST",

                    success: function(id){
                        alert ('success');
                        $('#participants tr:last').prev().remove();
                    }
```